# How do I configure TFS 2015 Version Control Permissions to allow anonymous git clone?

Tags: git, tfs, tfs-2015, ansible-galaxy

I am attempting to allow anonymous clone from our TFS 2015 git repositories so that ansible-galaxy can pull from our repos without having to log into git.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. You'll need to configure some form of authentication.